# How to set the resolution of the TSTZRANGE Postgres type?

Tags: postgresql, time, range

Postgres supports [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)<sub>([permalink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rangetypes.html))</sub> such as `int4range` or `tstzrange`. The documentation for `tstzrange` is "Range of `timestamp with time zone`".

The default precision for timestamps is to use 6 digits for second fractions (microsecond resolution), however my application uses 3 digits for its timestamps (millisecond) through `timestamp (3) with time zone`. For consistency I would like to also use millisecond-resolution for my time periods.

**What is the default `tstzrange` resolution? How can I configure it?**

I tried to define my table using `tstzrange(3)` but this form is not supported. Applied to the example from the documentation, it would look like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    during tstzrange(3),
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (during WITH &&)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Postgres 13, the time resolution for `tstzrange` uses 6 digit for second fractions (microsecond resolution). This resolution cannot be changed.

To create a range between timestamps with a custom resolution, you have to define a new range type. Here is the query to create a timestamp range with a millisecond resolution:

```sql
CREATE TYPE tstzrange3 AS RANGE (
  subtype = timestamp (3) with time zone
);
```

This defines both the `tstzrange3` type as well as a constructor function with the same name.

You can use this type like any other range:

```sql
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    during tstzrange3,
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (during WITH &&)
);

INSERT INTO reservation(during) VALUES(tstzrange3(NOW(), NULL));
```